# Conditionless GOTO in udev rules (and Medion RC-0617)

Tags: debian, hid, udev

I've been reverse-engineering a Medion RC-0617 remote control (with USB dongle) under some Debian 8.8 derivate (antix16).

It registers 3 different HID devices (/dev/hidraw*), and I wanted those to be symlinked to /dev/mdremote0, 1 and 2, independent of the numbers of the associated hidraw devices (which were hidraw1, 2 and 3 most of the time, but that varied depending on the plugged-in input devices) in order to query them with a script to execute custom actions for the remote control buttons.
(while at the same time setting their file mode to 666 in order to access them as regular user)

The output of udevadm info -a /dev/hidraw1 looked like this (shortened):

```
// The actual hidraw device (top level)
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:05:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:04F2:0618.002B/hidraw/hidraw1':
    KERNEL=="hidraw1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw"
    DRIVER==""
//...

// The last point at which the 3 individual hidraw devices differed from each other
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:05:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usbhid"
    //...
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01"
    // This entry distinguished the 3 individual hidraw devices from each other
    //...

// The dongle itself, parent device of all 3 hidraw devices
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:05:00.0/usb3/3-1':
    KERNELS=="3-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f2"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0618"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB Wireless HID Receiver"
    // The dongle can be uniquely identified by idVendor and idProduct
    //...
//...
```

So, the udev rules I needed to write would need to:

- Identify one parent device by idVendor and idProduct
- check the bInterfaceProtocol attribute in another parent device
- assign the right symlink /dev/mdremote* to the device and set the correct permissions

My first attempt at this came out like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0618", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01", SYMLINK="mdremote0", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0618", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00", SYMLINK="mdremote1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0618", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="02", SYMLINK="mdremote2", MODE="0666"
```

(order of bInterfaceProtocol attributes is intended)

Shortly said, this does not work, udev manpage says:

> Some of the keys also match against properties of the parent devices
>   in sysfs, not only the device that has generated the event. If
>   multiple keys that match a parent device are specified in a single
>   rule, all these keys must match at one and the same parent device.

So, I started another approach: First match against the dongle, then skip the individual rules if this check did not match, like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0618", GOTO="match"
GOTO="end"
LABEL="match"
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01", SYMLINK="mdremote0", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00", SYMLINK="mdremote1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="02", SYMLINK="mdremote2", MODE="0666"
LABEL="end"
```

This looks correct in the first term. But, guess what, it does not work either, the mdremote* symlinks just pointed to any device that had the bInterfaceProtocol key set.

Comment: Yes, that sounds useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the second line (GOTO="end") was just ignored. It took me some time to figure that out, but the solution is actually pretty simple:

If there are no conditions to match against, udev treats the rule as "always not matching" and therefore does not execute the GOTO at all.

My working udev rules file looked like this:

```
# Test if the wanted dongle is a parent device
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0618", GOTO="match"
# If not, skip the next 3 rules. The test against SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw" is there to produce a rule match
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", GOTO="end"
LABEL="match"
# Those 3 rules actually assign the right symlink depending on the bInterfaceProtocol property.
# Note that ALL of those rules contain the SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw" check, because the GOTO in the second line
# does not get executed for non-hidraw devices and the rules get evaluated for any non-hidraw device.
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01", SYMLINK="mdremote0", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00", SYMLINK="mdremote1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="02", SYMLINK="mdremote2", MODE="0666"
LABEL="end"
```

This turned out to work fine. It can still be improved by providing a better match rule for the GOTO="end" statement, but I left it that way.

Comment: Thank you for posting this! 48 hours have passed, so you can now self-accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

@orwell I found this by chance and was a bit confused why this did not work for you. I have tried to do something similiar and had no problems with an unconditional GOTO and debian stretch, as well as on Arch Linux. Check this:

```
[c0d3@z3r0 tmp]$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/45-test.rules
GOTO="end"
IMPORT{program}=="/bin/touch /tmp/noend"
LABEL="end"
IMPORT{program}=="/bin/touch /tmp/end"
[c0d3@z3r0 tmp]$ sudo udevadm control --reload 
[c0d3@z3r0 tmp]$ sudo udevadm trigger
[c0d3@z3r0 tmp]$ ls /tmp/*end
/tmp/end
[c0d3@z3r0 tmp]$
```

Comment: Hm, I already wrote my example that was not working... but I don't want to fiddle with this anymore, thanks